# C# Regex ask for "Parameter" and return "Value" for command line parse

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible create Regex pattern for parse command line request?

Like:`something text -PARAMETER="Hello world" something else.. -PARAMETER=HelloWorld`

I want to ask for `-PARAMETER` and get two items `"Hello world"` (OR just `Hello world`) and second occurrence `HelloWorld`

Thanks

EDIT:
Sorry for an austere question. My question is what is the best method of Regex or something better for this problem. 
In regex I used this pattern: `-PARAMETER=".*"|-PARAMETER=.*?\s` , but I mean that can be better. 
One of possible method:

```
string command = "PARAMETER";
string pattern = $"-{command}= \".*\" | -{command}=.*?\\s";
foreach (Match _m in Regex.Matches(CommandBlockArgs, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
  Console.WriteLine(_m.Value.Replace($"-{command}=", "").Replace("\"", "").Trim());
}
// *sorry for possible error, I wrote code now by head.*
```

But, also I mean that this is not nice solution.

For example, for me nice method for parse command by quotation marks is:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr CommandLineToArgvW(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCmdLine, out int pNumArgs);

public static string[] CommandLineToArgs(string commandLine)
{
  int argc;
  var argv = CommandLineToArgvW(commandLine, out argc);
  if (argv == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
    try
    {
      var args = new string[argc];
      for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
      {
        var p = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(argv, i * IntPtr.Size);
        args[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(p);
      }
      return args;
    }
    finally
    {
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(argv);
    }
 }
```

But here is not my commands list. And Regex can be better.. Or combination?

*Sorry for English =)

Comment: Are you aware of the umpteen libraries around for parsing of command lines?

Comment: It is possible to create a Regex pattern to parse any string.  What is actually your problem?

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes its possible, but i dont want use third party library, if possible. I have just simple method for call my methods with parameters. And use external library, I mean, is not necessary. Must exist different simple and elegant solution.

Comment: @LordWilmore thank you for your answer. Do you know the best pattern for this solution? And method, what can be use. Pls, dont compare with my (edited) solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution (C# 5.0):

```
    internal static object CallMethod(Type type, string method, string parameters)
    {
        MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod(method, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        ParameterInfo[] p = m.GetParameters();
        object[] param = new object[p.Count()];
        UInt16 i = 0;
        foreach (ParameterInfo pi in p)
        {
            string pattern = $"-{pi.Name}=\".*\"|-{pi.Name}=.*?\\s"; // -paramName=paramValue || -paramName="param Value"
            foreach (Match _m in Regex.Matches(parameters, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Type paramType = pi.ParameterType;
                string value = Regex.Replace(_m.Value, $"-{pi.Name}=", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace("\"", "").Trim();
                param[i] = Convert.ChangeType(value, pi.ParameterType);
            }
            i++;
        }
        return m.Invoke(null, param);
    }
```

It works, but maybe could be better.